# Getting 302 on a php mail($toEmail, $emailSubject, $body, $headers);

Tags: php, html, contact-form

I have a hostinger instance just for testing with 2 files on it
index.html and contact.php

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Simple contact Form</title>
</head>

<body>
    <form action="contact2.php" method="post">
        <input name="firstName" placeholder="firstName" type="text" size="30" />
        <input name="lastName" placeholder="lastName" type="text" size="30" />
        <input name="email" placeholder="email" type="text" size="30" />
        <input name="submit" type="submit" value="Send This">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

the php code

```
<?php

    $firstName = $_POST['firstName'];
    $lastName = $_POST['lastName'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $toEmail = 'myemail@mydomain.com';
    $emailSubject = "Contact Form:";
    $headers = ['From' => $email, 'Reply-To' => $email];
    $body = "Name: $firstName $lastName";
    mail($toEmail, $emailSubject, $body, $headers);
    header("Location: index.html"); 
?>
```

Results: The mail is not being sent (or received) & there the status is 302 redirect not sure why.

Comment: `302` is a status not an error, it's telling the browser that the site has redirected to a page

Comment: @BurhanKashour the email is not sent (or received),I'm trying to figure out 
1) why the mail is not functioning
2) why I get 302

Comment: Lots of missing information here. Where is the request redirected? What, if any, errors do the logs contain? I'd start by making sure the request is properly authenticated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the line `header("Location: index.html");`
and it will resolve the 302 status and will return 200.